# What is the reason of HttpMessageNotWritableException in my project?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am new to spring and programming overall. I am making a bookstore project to learn. I wanted to add a search feature to my project, where a user can find a book by title,genre and author. However, when I try to implement it, I get a org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException
Here is my repository, I user POSTGRESQL:

```
@Repository
public interface BooksRepository extends JpaRepository<Books,Long> {

    Optional<Books> findById(Long id);

    @Query(value = "SELECT b.id,b.title,b.price,b.book_description,b.genre,b.language,b.publisher_id,b.quantity" +
            " FROM books b WHERE b.title LIKE (%:query%)",nativeQuery = true)
    List<Books> searchBookByTitle(String query);

    @Query(value = "SELECT b.id,b.title,b.price,b.book_description,b.genre,b.language,b.publisher_id,b.quantity" +
            " FROM books b WHERE b.genre LIKE (%:query%)",nativeQuery = true)
    List<Books> searchBookByGenre(String query);
    @Query(value = "SELECT b.id,b.title,b.price,b.book_description,b.genre,b.language,b.publisher_id,b.quantity FROM books b inner join books_and_authors bas on b.id = bas.book_id " +
            "inner join authors a on bas.author_id = a.id WHERE a.name LIKE (%:query%)",nativeQuery = true)
    List<Books> searchByAuthor(String query);
```

Here is my service:

```
@Override
public Set<Books> searchBooks(String query) {
    List<Books> booksTitle = booksRepository.searchBookByTitle(query);
    List<Books> booksGenre = booksRepository.searchBookByGenre(query);
    List<Books> booksAuthor = booksRepository.searchByAuthor(query);
    Set<Books> books = Stream.of(booksTitle,booksGenre,booksAuthor)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    return books;
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
 @RestController
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/books")
    public class BookController {
    
        private final BookService bookService;
        @GetMapping("/search")
        public ResponseEntity<Set<Books>> searchBook(@RequestParam(value = "query") String query){
            return ResponseEntity.ok(bookService.searchBooks(query));
        }
    }
```

Here is module:

```
@Entity(name = "Books")
@Table(name = "books")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Books {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator( name = "book_sequence",
                        sequenceName = "book_sequence",
                        allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
                    generator = "book_sequence")
    @Column(name = "id",
            updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "title",
            nullable = false,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "genre",
            nullable = false,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String genre;

    @Column(name = "price",
            nullable = false,
            columnDefinition = "FLOAT")
    private Double price;

    @Column(name = "quantity",
            nullable = false,
            columnDefinition = "BIGINT")
    private Integer quantity;

    @Column(name = "language",
            nullable = false,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String language;

    @Column(name = "book_description",
            columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String bookDescription;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book")
    private List<Liked> userLikedBook = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book")
    private List<Carts> userAddedBookToCart = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book")
    private List<Reviews> reviews;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
                mappedBy = "books")
    private List<BooksAndAuthors> booksAndAuthors = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "publisher_id",
            nullable = false,
            referencedColumnName = "id",
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(
                    name = "publisher_book_fk"
            ))
    private Publishers publisher;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book")
    private List<OrderDetails> orderDetails;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book")
    private List<Orders> orders;
}
```